# User taxonomy by location

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms, location

I am trying to add taxonomy to my user location.

User A lives in Berkshire, UK, User B clicks at "berkshire, Uk" in Profil of User A and get a list of all Users who lives there. For example look at my picture.

[image: http://www.upload-pictures.de/bild.php/28053,userlocationtaxonomy1V987.png]

If I have only 1 field like city or country it would be no problem. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create a taxonomy called Location with hierarchy like Country > City. That's really it. You can use views to style the output page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i still have some questions. I created a new vocabulary called location and insert Country -> City as Term. After that i created a new user field country and city as term reference field with autocomplete widget. But now i want items from the city field are automatically add as child terms of city. Same with the country field. How can this be done?

Comment: Why don't you prepopulate the taxonomy with the countries and cities and have your users select from the list instead. You could use Hierarchical Select module to display the hierarchy in the form. This will make the name of countries consistent since users may type it incorrectly if they enter it themselves. List of countries are easy to find online and you can mass upload them with taxonomy manager module.